# What is the correct usage of the method Parallelize in the Spark module pyspark.mllib.classification

Tags: apache-spark-mllib

1. Running Databricks Community Edition spark cluster from Notebook UI
2. Facing this error when attempting to train a NaiveBayes for a tiny data sample - ***TypeError: unbound method parallelize() must be called with
   SparkContext instance as first argument (got list instance instead)***
3. Code :

   ```
   from pyspark.mllib.classification import LabeledPoint, NaiveBayes
   from pyspark import SparkContext as sc
   data = [
   LabeledPoint(0.0, [0.0, 0.0]),
   LabeledPoint(0.0, [0.0, 1.0]),
   LabeledPoint(1.0, [1.0, 0.0])]
   model = NaiveBayes.train(sc.parallelize(data))
   model.predict(array([0.0, 1.0]))
   model.predict(array([1.0, 0.0]))
   model.predict(sc.parallelize([[1.0, 0.0]])).collect()
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the import on line two of your example:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext as sc
```

This is overwriting the built-in `SparkContext` instance (stored in `sc`) with the `SparkContext` class, causing the later `sc.parallelize()` call to fail.

In Databricks, you don't need to create the SparkContext yourself; it's automatically pre-defined as `sc` in Databricks notebooks. See https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/getting-started.html#predefined-variables for a more complete list of pre-defined variables in Databricks.